# How to remove class from webview

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to remove this div:

```
<div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="bottom" class="ui-navbar" role="navigation">
    <ul class="ui-grid-b">
        <li class="ui-block-a">
            <a href="http://www.siverekhaber.net/mobil/galeriler.html" data-icon="camera"
               class="ui-link ui-btn ui-icon-camera ui-btn-icon-bottom">Galeri</a>
        </li>
        <li class="ui-block-b">
            <a href="http://www.siverekhaber.net/mobil/videolar.html" data-icon="video"
               class="ui-link ui-btn ui-icon-video ui-btn-icon-bottom">Video</a>
        </li>
        <li class="ui-block-c">
            <a href="http://www.siverekhaber.net/mobil/yazarlar.html" data-icon="edit"
               class="ui-link ui-btn ui-icon-edit ui-btn-icon-bottom">Yazarlar</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I tried overriding the `onPageFinished` method:

```
@Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        final Animation fade = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
        fade.setDuration(200);
        view.startAnimation(fade);
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mRefreshPbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mRefreshBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        updateActionView();
        mWebview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
            "if (typeof(document.getElementsByClassName('ui-footer')[0]) != 'undefined' && document.getElementsByClassName('ui-footer')[0] != null){"+
            "document.getElementsByClassName('ui-footer')[0].style.display = 'none';"+
            "})()");
    }
```

but it's not working. What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `void 0` to prevent the browser from redirecting to a plain text file.

```
mWebview.loadUrl("javascript:if (typeof(document.getElementsByClassName('ui-footer')[0]) != 'undefined' && document.getElementsByClassName('ui-footer')[0] != null){document.getElementsByClassName('ui-footer')[0].style.display = 'none';} void 0");
```

Comment: thanks for advice. but it's still not working. can you check the site please ? it is www.siverekhaber.net/mobil when i remove ui-navbar div manually it gone but javascript is not working.

Comment: OK, fixed. You don't need the function call. It took me a while because Chrome had a bug...

Comment: I tried 
mWebview.loadUrl("javascript: " +
                        "if (typeof(document.getElementsByClassName('ui-navbar')[0]) != 'undefined' && document.getElementsByClassName('ui-navbar')[0] != null){"+
                        "document.getElementsByClassName('ui-navbar')[0].style.display = 'none';"+
                        "");
but it's still not working.

Comment: Can you explain on that more? Is the onPageFinished() called? Or maybe a screenshot?

Comment: onPageFinished() is a method which run automatically after page loaded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76302/discussion-between-jyoon-and-dauezevy).